# How to download multiple images **sequentially** through an array of url on Andriod using Java

Tags: java, android, image, mobile

Please, I am trying to implement a multiple image download on my android project using java. There is an array of URLs and an ArrayList of bitmap where the bitmap is stored when downloaded. The challenge is that it's not downloading sequentially due to size and the images with smaller sizes get downloaded and stored in the bitmap Arraylist ahead of the larger ones hence the Arraylist of the bitmap is disorganized.

```
private void downloadAndStoreImage(List<String> bitmapUrl) {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapUrl.size(); i++) {
            imageLoader.loadImage(bitmapUrl.get(i), new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    bitmaps.add(loadedImage);
                   

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks @Raubsauger, please the bitmap is downloading quite well but it should be able to download it sequencially. For instance, if the image1 url is in index 0 in the bitmapUrl Array, the Image1 bitmap should be downloaded into bitmaps Array at index 0. But the challenge is that Image3 can download faster due to lighter size and be stored on bitmaps array at index 0. Any idea on how to correct this?

Comment: If you know you will download `n` images, why not create an array of `n` elements, and insert each downloaded image into the array at index `i` (the `i` from the for-loop). Then it doesn't matter if the images are downloaded sequentially or out of order...